# Como pegar fazer um splice() em um http.get usando Ionic / Angularjs para pesquisa?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Quero filtrar de acordo com o que o usuário digitar na tela. Tenho um form com o `ng-model="q"` e o `| filter:q`

Onde meu http.get passo os parametros que estou filtrando, onde o ng-model é o parametro "buscar:

```
$scope.pagination = {
        limit: 10,
        offset: 0
    };
    $scope.pagination.limit = 8;
    $scope.pagination.offset = 0;
    $scope.q = '';
    $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = false;
    $scope.ofertass = [];
    $scope.getRecord = function () {
        $http.get("http://meusite.com.br/admin/apis/api_listagem/lista_oferta_api.php?json=promocao" + "&latitude=" + $scope.lat_cliente + "&longitude=" + $scope.long_cliente + "&raio=" + $scope.raio + "&limit=" + $scope.pagination.limit + "&offset=" + $scope.pagination.offset + "&busca=" + $scope.q).then(function (response) {
                // console.log(response.data);
                if (response.data.length) {
                    $scope.ofertass.push.apply($scope.ofertass, response.data);
                    $scope.pagination.offset = $scope.pagination.offset + $scope.pagination.limit;
                    window.localStorage.setItem("data_ofertass", JSON.stringify(response.data));

                } else {
                    $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = true;
                    if (window.localStorage.getItem("data_ofertass") === null) {
                        $state.go("nhaac.nachegamos");
                    }

                }
            },
            function (response) {
                // error message
                var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: "error " + response.status,
                    template: response.statusText + "<br/>Problema: Conexão com sua Internet.",
                });
            }).finally(function () {
            console.log("finally....");
            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');

        });
    }

    $scope.doRefresh = function () {
        limit = 20;
        offset = 0;
        $scope.q = '';
        $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = false;
        $scope.getRecord();
    };
```

Funciona bem, mas quando esvazio o campo de busca me retorna resultados em branco com o último filtro lá em baixo.

Segue meu search na View:

```
<center>
        <form ng-submit="fechaTeclado()">
            <div class="bar bar-subheader bar-light">
                <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
                    <input type="text" size="100" ng-model="q" placeholder="Procurar" type="submit" ng-submit="fechaTeclado()" ng-click="fechaTeclado()" />
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="OK" ng-click="fechaTeclado()" />

                </label>
            </div>
        </form>
    </center>
```

O que estou fazendo de errado? Testo a URL com os parametros e funciona bem...

Se deixo "&busca=" vazio me lista tudo. Isso é correto. Mas na minha aplicação, não está limpando a busca.

**EDITADO:**

Tem a função FechaTeclado() que é apenas para fechar o teclado do aparelho:

```
$scope.fechaTeclado = function (q) {
    $cordovaKeyboard.close();
    $scope.q = q;        
    $scope.getRecord();
};
```

Penso em utilizar um slice() ou splice() no getRecord, para eliminar o que não deve parecer:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe na imagem a cima, que ficam espaços em branco que eram preenchidos antes do filtro, e se arrastar mostra o que foi buscado.

Mas estou em uma lógica boa de como fazer isso.

Comment: Cara não consegui entender bem o que está errado. Qual era a sua duvida? Essa linha não entendi -> Funciona bem, mas quando esvazio o campo de busca me retorna resultados em branco com o último filtro lá em baixo.

Comment: Vou capturar as telas e editar a pergunta.

Comment: Quantos pontos tenho que ter para dar recompensa na pergunta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi com POG!

Segue:

```
$scope.fechaTeclado = function () {
            $cordovaKeyboard.close();

            if ($scope.q === '') {
                $scope.q = '';
                window.localStorage.setItem("q", $scope.q);
                $scope.pagination = {
                    limit: 10,
                    offset: 0
                };
                $scope.pagination.limit = 8;
                $scope.pagination.offset = 0;
                $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = false;
                $scope.ofertass = [];

                $scope.getRecord();

            } else {



                window.localStorage.setItem("q", $scope.q);

             //   $scope.q = window.localStorage.getItem("q");

                $scope.pagination = {
                    limit: 10,
                    offset: 0
                };
                $scope.pagination.limit = 8;
                $scope.pagination.offset = 0;
                $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = false;
                $scope.ofertass = [];

                $scope.getRecord();
            }
        };
```