# infinite scroll com angular problema em carregar dados do BD

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, banco-de-dados, script

Estou tentado implementar o Infinite Scroll ao meu projeto e seguindo algumas aulas que encontrei na internet cheguei a este código:

```
<?php 
$query = "SELECT * FROM produtos ORDER BY id DESC";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conectar, $query);

while($linhas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){ 
$imagem = pg.'/media/'.$linhas['imagem'];
$prod_nome = $linhas['nome'];
$prod_nome = str_replace(" ","-",$prod_nome);
$link_prod = pg.'/produto/'.$linhas['id'].'/'.$vid_nome;
?>

<div ng-controller="ContentsController" >
<div infinite-scroll="contents.nextPage()" infinite-scroll-distance="2" infinite-scroll-disabled="contents.busy">
    <span ng-repeat="content in contents.items">

<div id="{{content.id}}" class="col-sm-4 m-b-15" title="{{content.nome}}">
<div class="well well-sm">
    <div class="thumb-overlay">
        <a href="http://teste.com/{{content.id}}/{{content.nome}}">
            <div class="thumb-overlay">
                <img src="http://teste.com/{{content.imagem}}" id="{{content.imagem}}" class="img-responsive ">                                                         
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class="actions"></div>
    </div>
    <a href="http://teste.com/{{content.id}}/{{content.nome}}">
        <div class="title title-truncate">{{content.nome}}</div>
    </a>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>                                        
</div>
</div>
    </span>
</div>
</div>

<script>
(function(){

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['infinite-scroll']);
myApp.controller('ContentsController', function($scope, Contents) {
    $scope.contents = new Contents();
});

myApp.factory('Contents', function ($http) {
    var Contents = function(){
        this.items = [];
        this.busy = false;
        this.page = 1;
    }

    Contents.prototype.nextPage = function(){
        if(this.busy) return;
        this.busy = true;
        var url = 'http://teste.com/produtos?page='+this.page;

        $http.get(url).success(function(data){
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                this.items.push(data[i]);
            };
            this.page++;
            this.busy = false;
        }.bind(this));
    };
    return Contents;    
});
}).call(this);
</script>
```

meu problema é que não consigo me conectar com a tabela "produtos" onde estão as informações que deveram ser exibidas. Alguém pode dizer onde e o que preciso alterar pra conectar com o BD? Obrigado.

Comment: Não é parecido com este: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220227/como-pegar-fazer-um-splice-em-um-http-get-usando-ionic-angularjs-para-pesqui ?

Comment: @Ramos no meu caso é uma página que lista todos os dados que estão no banco de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Na View, algo como on-infinite:

```
 <ion-list class="list">
            <div class="spacer" style="width: 300px; height: 90px;"></div>
            <ion-infinite-scroll ng-if="!noMoreItemsAvailable" on-infinite="onInfinite()" distance="5px" ng-if="hasMoreData"></ion-infinite-scroll>
        </ion-list>

        <ion-list class="list">
            <div class="item" ng-if="results.length == 0">
                <p>Nenhum resultado encontrado...</p>
            </div>
        </ion-list>


        <ion-infinite-scroll ng-if="!noMoreItemsAvailable" on-infinite="loadMore()" distance="10%">
            <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="bubbles">




    </ion-content>
    <!-- ./content -->
</ion-view>
```

E no controller, algo como:

```
// animation readmore
        var fetchItems = function () {
            for (var z = 0; z < fetch_per_scroll; z++) {
                if (angular.isObject(data_items[lastPush])) {
                    $scope.items.push(data_items[lastPush]);
                    lastPush++;
                } else {;
                    $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = true;
                }
            }
            $scope.$broadcast("scroll.infiniteScrollComplete");
        };
```

**EDITADO:**

E depois da função a cima, a função onInfinite:

```
// event readmore
        $scope.onInfinite = function () {
            $timeout(fetchItems, 500);
        };
```

Segue um controller completo, no http.get que faço chamada a api que conecta ao banco de dados:

```
$scope.scrollTop = function () {
            $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle("top").scrollTop();
        };
        // open external browser 
        $scope.openURL = function ($url) {
            window.open($url, "_system", "location=yes");
        };
        // open AppBrowser
        $scope.openAppBrowser = function ($url) {
            window.open($url, "_blank", "closebuttoncaption=Done");
        };
        // open WebView
        $scope.openWebView = function ($url) {
            window.open($url, "_self");
        };

        // Set Motion
        $timeout(function () {
            ionicMaterialMotion.slideUp({
                selector: ".slide-up"
            });
        }, 300);
        // animation loading 
        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: '<div class="loader"><svg class="circular"><circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/></svg></div>'
        });

        // Retrieving data
        var itemID = $stateParams.cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta;

        //    console.log('Abracadabra: ' + itemID);

        //    window.localStorage.setItem("fornecedor_temp", itemID);


        var current_item = [];
        if (window.localStorage.getItem("data_ofertass") !== "undefined") {
            var datas = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("data_ofertass"));
            for (var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
                if ((datas[i].cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta === parseInt(itemID)) || (datas[i].cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta === itemID.toString())) {
                    current_item = datas[i];
                }
            }
            // event done, hidden animation loading
            $timeout(function () {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                $scope.ofertas = current_item;
            }, 500);
        };

        if (!angular.isObject(current_item)) {
            var itemID = $stateParams.cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta;
            var current_item = [];
            $http.get("http://seusite_com_sua_api/admin/apis/api_listagem/lista_oferta_single_api.php?json=promocao").then(function (response) {
                // Get data single
                var datas = response.data;
                try {
                    window.localStorage.setItem("data_ofertass", JSON.stringify(datas));
                } catch (e) {
                    window.localStorage.clear();
                    window.localStorage.setItem("data_ofertass", JSON.stringify(datas));
                    $state.reload();
                    $scope.$state = $state;
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
                    if ((datas[i].cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta === parseInt(itemID)) || (datas[i].cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta === itemID.toString())) {
                        current_item = datas[i];
                    }
                }
            }, function (response) {
                // Error message
                var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: "error " + response.status,
                    template: response.statusText + "<br/>problem: table ofertas",
                });
            }).finally(function () {
                $scope.$broadcast("scroll.refreshComplete");
                // event done, hidden animation loading
                $timeout(function () {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    $scope.ofertas = current_item;


                }, 500);
            });
        }
        $scope.doRefresh = function () {
            // Retrieving data
            window.localStorage.clear();
            var itemID = $stateParams.cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta;
            var current_item = [];
            $http.get("http://seusite_comapi/admin/apis/api_listagem/lista_oferta_single_api.php?json=promocao").then(function (response) {
                // Get data single
                var datas = response.data;
                window.localStorage.setItem("data_ofertass", JSON.stringify(datas));
                for (var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
                    if ((datas[i].cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta === parseInt(itemID)) || (datas[i].cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta === itemID.toString())) {
                        current_item = datas[i];
                    }
                }
            }, function (response) {
                // Error message
                var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: "error " + response.status,
                    template: response.statusText + "<br/>problem: table ofertas",
                });
            }).finally(function () {
                $scope.$broadcast("scroll.refreshComplete");
                // event done, hidden animation loading
                $timeout(function () {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    $scope.ofertas = current_item;
                }, 500);
            });
        };



        //add to cart function
        $scope.addToCart = function (id, image, name, price, supply_id, deliver, tipopag, entrega) {
            // CHAMA CART.ADD DE SERVICES 
            window.localStorage.setItem("fonecedor_carrinho", supply_id);
            window.localStorage.setItem("tipos_pagamentos", tipopag);
            window.localStorage.setItem("frete", deliver);
            window.localStorage.setItem("faz_entrega", entrega);


            console.log("ID Fornecedor: " + supply_id);

            cart.add(id, image, name, price, 1, supply_id, deliver);

            $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                disableAnimate: true,
                disableBack: true
            });

            var adiciona = '1';
            window.localStorage.setItem("vazio", adiciona);

            $state.go("nhaac.carrinho");

        };

        // FAVORITAR
        $scope.addFavorite = function (id, image, name, supply_id) {


            // COLOCA TEMPORARIAMENTE EM LOCALSTORAGE
            window.localStorage.setItem("favorita_cod_oferta", id);
            window.localStorage.setItem("favorita_image", image);
            window.localStorage.setItem("favorita_oferta", name);
            window.localStorage.setItem("favorita_cod_fornecedor", supply_id);


            // PEGA DO LOCALSTORAGE E CRIA UM CAMPO

            $scope.f_cod_fornecedor = window.localStorage.getItem("favorita_cod_fornecedor");

            $scope.f_image = window.localStorage.getItem("favorita_image");

            $scope.f_oferta = window.localStorage.getItem("favorita_oferta");

            $scope.f_cod_oferta = window.localStorage.getItem("favorita_cod_oferta");

            $scope.cod_cliente = window.localStorage.getItem("cod_cliente");

            $ionicLoading.show();

            var url = "?cod_cliente=" + $scope.cod_cliente + "&cod_fornecedor=" + $scope.f_cod_fornecedor + "&imagem=" + $scope.f_image + "&oferta=" + $scope.f_oferta + "&cod_oferta=" + $scope.f_cod_oferta + ""
            console.log(url);


            var encodedurl = encodeURI(url);

            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    var responseishere = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    console.log(responseishere);
                    var myobj = JSON.parse(responseishere);
                    alert(myobj.message);
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                } else if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status != 200) {
                    alert("Server Error");
                    $ionicLoading.hide();

                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://vovocooks.com.br/admin/apis/put/favorita.php" + encodedurl, true);
            xmlhttp.send();

            alert("Hummm, que delícia! Favoritado com sucesso.");

            $state.go("nhaac.favoritos")

            // DELETA DO LOCALSTORAGE E CRIA UM CAMPO

            window.localStorage.removeItem("favorita_cod_oferta", id);
            window.localStorage.removeItem("favorita_image", image);
            window.localStorage.removeItem("favorita_oferta", name);
            window.localStorage.removeItem("favorita_cod_fornecedor", supply_id);
        };

        $scope.ChamaAvalia = function (vovo) {
            window.localStorage.setItem("cod_vovo_pedido", vovo);
            $state.go('nhaac.listaavalia');


        };

        var tipo = '';

        // $scope.checarPermissoes();

        $scope.checarPermissoes = function (tipo) {
            var permitido;

            if (tipo === 'logado_usuario' && window.localStorage.getItem("user_log") !== null) {
                permitido = true;
            } else {
                permitido = false;
            }

            return permitido;
        };




        // animation ink (ionic-material)
        ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();
        $scope.rating = {};
        $scope.rating.max = 5;
    })
```

Comment: Se não for isso, edite sua pergunta, colocando seu PHP....

Comment: poderia dizer onde o código a cima traz os dados da tabela do BD? Obrigado

Comment: Vou editar para mostrar...

Comment: inclui o php que estava usando antes de começar a estudar esse método

Answer (score 0):

Seu PHP, tente transformar em um JSON, como neste exemplo. Da forma que está fazendo, não sei se pega os resultados.

```
<?php


header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

include 'database.php';

//$cod_vovo=$_GET['cod_vovo'];


$query="SELECT 
   cod_avaliacao,
   cod_cliente,
   cod_fornecedor,
   AVG(avaliacao_geral)
FROM
   avaliacao 
GROUP BY cod_fornecedor";


$result=$con->query($query);

$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    $count=0;
    echo "[";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
            $count++;
            echo json_encode($row);

            if($count!=$row_cnt)
            {
                    echo ",";
            }


    }
    echo "]";
}
else
{
echo "error";
}

?>
```

Comment: para minha infelicidade não estou conseguindo incorporar, você teria alguma forma mais instantânea que você possa sanar minhas duvidas?